# RandomForest in R - Attaching Output to Object-ID

Tags: r, random-forest, spatial

I have mapped an area using object-based image analysis. This has resulted in 2000 image objects (polygons) that I want to classify based on their properties (spectral, RGB data, shape, size etc.).

I have saved the data as a .csv for use in 'Randomforest' package.

I have assigned "Habitat Level" as one of six factors for each object in the data (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6). Example of the csv attached.

[data used for randomforest, csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmMIe.png)

What I want to do is run randomforest to predict a "Habitat_Level" to each of the image objects (Column: OBJECT_ID).

So the result I need will fill the "PREDICTED" column with "Habitat_Level" (generated from random forest) that uses the OBJECT_ID to discriminate between objects.

I have run the randomforest but I don't know how to assign the classification to existing OBJECT_ID

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, make your question reproducible. This includes sample code you've attempted, non-base R packages that you are using or that you plan on using, any errors/warnings received, and sample data, like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))` (not an attachment). Check out these resources for great questions: [making R questions reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). There are hundreds of packages with a random forest model–you said you've already tried to run one. Which package did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `predict` function to generate predictions for each row in your dataset.

It's hard to give some code without seeing the code you've used so far, and a cut of your data, but something like this should work:

```
data$PREDICTED <- predict(yourmodel, data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is great.

I worked out how to commit the OBJECT_ID to being the unique identifier and now with your help I can populate the PREDICTED field with RF data from R

Much appreciated.